# Установка и настройка bootstrap

Tags: twitter, bootstrap, html

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с bootstrap'ом. Он никак не хочет отображать документы нормально. Появляются лишь элементы меню, но в стандартном браузерном оформлении.
Пользовался инструкцией с хабра: [пользовательский интерфейс на базе Twitter Bootstrap для начинающих](http://habrahabr.ru/post/138818/).

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего ошибка в `href`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Это можно проверить через firebug. Если у элемента установлен бутстраповский класс, а по нему к этому элементу не привязываются стили, значит браузер не находит css-файл.